# border issue in chrome

Tags: html, css

I have used border-radius in my form field. It works fine. But the chrome it appears some line around the filed. Please refer the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/JKdzc/

Please help me.

Comment: Thank You for your reply. I followed your code and implemented it. It works fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you referring to the orange highlight? If so, add this style:

```
outline:none;
```

Answer (score 1):

Chrome adds a yellow/orange **outline** when users focus on an input.  Remove it like this:

```
input:focus
{
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The orange outline is Chrome's way of focusing the users attention on to what they have clicked. As mentioned previously, the best way to get rid of this is `outline:none;` in the CSS.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Probably this is just a bug in WebKit. There are a lot of known issues with WebKit having trouble with `border-radius`.

You can check out whether the bug already has been added to [the buglist](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list?can=2&q=border+radius&colspec=ID+Pri+Mstone+ReleaseBlock+Area+Feature+Status+Owner+Summary&cells=tiles).

**UPDATE**

As [jezternz noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683844/border-issue-in-chrome/10683900#comment-13865272) you can workaround this by using the `style` attribute. Alternatievely you can add a wrapper around the `select` element and do the [styling on that](http://jsfiddle.net/JKdzc/6/).

Comment: I have used this style text field tag. It works good. This issue displays in select tag.